# Scikit-learn: _count_vocab is throwing empty vocabulary error

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm passing two strings for example: `$1-2$ $3-4$ 5-6$` & `$7-8$ $9-10$ $10-11$`

In such case the count_vocab function is throwing an error:

```
empty vocabulary: perhaps the document contains only stop words"
```

So does it have a problem with the $ symbol?

Does it not consider $1-2$ as a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a token is determined by the `token_pattern` argument (a regular expression) to the [`CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) constructor:

```
Regular expression denoting what constitutes a "token", only used
if `tokenize == 'word'`. The default regexp select tokens of 2
or more alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored
and always treated as a token separator).
```

This obviously doesn't match what you have, so define a different RE for your data.